# Re-numbering sub-sets of a table in SQL

Tags: sql, azure

I have a table which contains columns for: ComponentID, PartID, Position, Country and City. The primary key consists of ComponentID, PartID, Country and City.

I am using MS SQL Azure.

Potentially a "part" may be deleted. If this happens, I need to be able to reset all of the positions for components and parts, BUT partitioned by Country and city.

I have written the code below, but it throws a primary key error. Can anyone help?

```
-- Update the positions 
;WITH CTE AS
    (
            SELECT Comp.Position,
               RowNum = row_number() OVER (partition by Comp.Country, Comp.City order by Comp.Position ASC)
            FROM Comp
        WHERE Comp.CompID = @selectedComponent
    )
UPDATE CTE 
SET Position = RowNum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CTE is generating the new row positions for your data so you then need to Join that to your existing table to update the position values.

To do that, you will need to include all the primary key columns in the CTE, and then do an update over a join:

```
UPDATE dbo.Comp 
    SET Position = CTE.RowNum
    FROM CTE
    INNER JOIN DBO.Comp ON   CTE.ComponentId  = dbo.Comp.ComponentId
    AND CTE.City = dbo.Comp.City AND CTE.Country = dbo.Comp.Country AND CTE.PartID = dbo.Comp.PartID
```